# openshift django multiple sqlite databases set up

Tags: django, sqlite, openshift

I have three sqlite3 databases for my django project. Now, I want to know what's the correct set up for all three databases. My application runs perfectly from my localhost. However, openshift can't detect my other databases and therefore I keep getting a server error. I'm struggling to find a perfect answer.

```
#settings.py   
import os
DJ_PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(DJ_PROJECT_DIR)
WSGI_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
REPO_DIR = os.path.dirname(WSGI_DIR)
DATA_DIR = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR', BASE_DIR)


import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(REPO_DIR, 'libs'))
import json

try:
    with open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'secrets.json')) as handle:
        SECRETS = json.load(handle)
except IOError:
    SECRETS = { 'secret_key': 'a' }
....

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # GETTING-STARTED: change 'db.sqlite3' to your sqlite3 database:
        'NAME': os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'db2.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db3': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'db3.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having three separate sqlite files? Why are you using sqlite at all in production? Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Basically, I'm creating an sql injection application. So, I don't want to use my default db.sqlite3 for my example. So, I'm using db2.sqlite3 like this: login.objects.using('db2').raw(query) and it's giving me server error 500. To be honest, openshift is hell confusing. There's no easy solution.

Comment: Where are you actually wanting the databases to be stored? The ``OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`` environment variable is not set by default in OpenShift 3, so your databases will end up in your project directory. This isn't a persistent directory and on a restart the databases will be lost.

Comment: Yes, Graham that's true basically I just realised that now [link](https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-django-applications-openshift-3/). But it's hell confusing to set up the environment variable. Do you know any source or can you please kindly give me a simple explanation?

Comment: Have you read the free eBooks at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html and https://www.openshift.com/promotions/devops-with-openshift.html There is also the interactive learning environment at https://learn.openshift.com/

Comment: Also read through https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-django-applications-openshift-3/ which talks about adapting V2 environments variables in V3.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not wasting my time anymore. I've read mostly all of them and found none of them useful. Probably going to switch onto a different platform. Openshift isn't easy anymore.